# Delete depended documents in from the depended collection if any collection throw error in the process

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have 3 mongo dB collection depended on each other but when i create the documents in the collection I want to delete the created documents if any other depended collection throw the error in the process.

What will be the better way to manage this.

my use case:
i have one controller where when customer submit the survey where i check if that customer already exist then i will not create customer else will create that customer in customer collection and then go to the reward function where i create the reward for the customer and then send the reward mail to the customer's email. then check in survey collection if survey already exist i throw the error if not then success response.

so how to delete depended collection's record if any collection get error while inserting the document.

I am thinking to check if i got the error in next function then i will delete the latest record from the above collection but that does not seems the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

please see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/

> When a transaction aborts, all data changes made in the transaction are discarded without ever becoming visible. For example, if any operation in the transaction fails, the transaction aborts and all data changes made in the transaction are discarded without ever becoming visible.